# How to record every transaction forwarded to my node（geth）?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

With a geth client,how can i record every transaction forwarded to me by other nodes (hash, node IP, timestamp) ,in the network layer?It does not mean I am the receiver of the transaction.I just want to know who i am connected to and who propagated a transactiion to me? a little curious.Thanks very much!!!!!!